# Do I need to include www for cross domain tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I'm setting up cross domain tracking in Google Analytics on a site with www and I'm wondering if that should be included in the code or just the base URL.

For example, my main site is www.mainsite.com and we are linking to a third-party shopping cart that will be at shop.mainsite.com. So what should the tracking code look like?

According to a GA help toopic on setting up cross-domain tracking https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en it says to add additional code, so I added:

```
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.mainsite.com', 'shop.mainsite.com']);
```

To my tracking script. Was this correct? One person told me that I don't have to add this to have cross-domain tracking, but when I go to setup ecommerce in GA, it says in this topic https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009612?hl=en&ref_topic=1037061 that I need to setup cross-domain tracking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in terms of cross-domain tracking (not considering eComm), from your primary domain (www.mainsite.com), you just need to add

```
ga('linker:autoLink', ['shop.mainsite.com']);
```

and on your secondary domain (shop.mainsite.com), add

```
ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.mainsite.com']);
```

(Note that this needs to happen on every page of both domains.)

You can glean more from this link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en